# Powershell using Robocopy to list files in csv

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I have been asked to provide a listing of all files in a folder and its subfolders.

Initial efforts using powershell and dos commands proved it was unable to cope with file and folder names that exceeded windows 256 character length limit so I decided I had to use robocopy to get a listing of all files.

This worked great but output is logged in a text file. Most of the output is tab delimited so I have figured out a way to convert this to a csv.

The problem I am having is there is a space between the file size and the date. After conversion to csv the "filesize, date and time" all exists within the same column when the csv is opened in excel. I dont mind the date and time being in the same column but I need fileszie to be in its own column.

So the question is, how can I replace the space between filesize and date with ","  (including the doublequotes) using a powershell command.

I cannot replace all spaces as there might be spaces in some of the file name

Hope I have explained this as clearly as possible.

TIA

Comment: Please show us what you've done, script-wise, with a [mcve], and sample dataset between what's 'right' and 'wrong,' as opposed to describing it rather broadly.  Otherwise, it's difficult to nail down exactly how to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PowerShell below uses robocopy to generate a directory listing as PowerShell objects:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Deeply-Nested-Files-a2148fd7

There is a blog post to go with it

https://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/01/list-all-files-regardless-of-260-character-path-restriction-using-powershell-and-robocopy/

With the above you can do:

```
 Get-FolderItem -Path "<yourpath>" | ConvertTo-Csv
```

Comment: Brilliant, wish I had found that earlier. Took a while to work out but glad I did

Answer (score 0):

So I know your question is requesting RoboCopy, and I'll give you a way to do that at the bottom, but imo the best way to deal with 255+ char file names is with the .net library [AlphaFS](http://alphafs.alphaleonis.com/).  once you import the module getting a nice set of objects is just a method call away.  If you just need the names of the files this will work:

```
[Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory]::GetFiles($path)
```

If you need more information you'll need 2 lines

```
$d = [Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.DirectoryInfo]($path)
$d.GetFiles("*","AllDirectories")
```

If your stuck on using RoboCopy then you can always do a `-replace` to replace the tabs with spaces and then do a convertfrom-csv with a space delimiter.

Comment: *the best way to deal with 255+ char file names is with the .net library AlphaFS* - are you advocating this over Windows 10 Anniversary Update with the 250 character limit removal setting?

Comment: if you want the code to be portable to anything other than a fully updated copy of win 10 then yes

Comment: Will try your method if I get a chance tomorrow.

Comment: Will try your method if I get a chance tomorrow.

I have already been working with -repace, but that will not work as I already explained some of the file names have spaces which will then be replaced by comma's and cause the csv file to turn into a mess.

Therefore need a way to convert "." so need to know what a different escape character is I can use or alternately I might have to look at inserting "." at a specific distance from the left of the file

Comment: ahh ic, I remember working on this at some point earlier this year but I can't remember if I ever got it working and looking back I can find the code I used to get size totals from robocopy but can't seem to locate any full file listing functions.  think I moved to AlphaFS before I got it fully working but iirc I was leaning towards a solution that used some pretty complex substring and index methods on each string to try and parse it out correctly.  You could probably make a regex work as well if your comfortable with them.  If AlphaFS won't work for you lmk I'll have another go at it 2moro

Comment: I did find the substring in the end.  -Replace " ", "`"" but that unfortunately replaced spaces in files also so was looking at a way of replacing it only within one column of a csv which I guess would have worked but then saw the post below that seems to work perfectly

Comment: glad you got something working for you.  personally still prefer the AlphaFS library since you get a bit more flexibility but to each their own.